# CJK Compatibility Forms characters in character-map

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am having a problem with mapping characters in CJK Compatibility Forms unicode block. An example is below

```
<xsl:output-character character="⁡︷" string="&amp;#xFE37;"/>
```

I am getting an error as such:

```
XTSE0020: character attribute must be a single XML character
```

Is there any workaround with this?

Comment: deleting the line above and having `<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO8859-1">` seems to do the trick. But, is there a way to do that using the `xsl:character-map`?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be sure exactly what that character is (you haven't told us anything about encoding), but it looks to me to be the 6-octet UTF-8 sequence

e2 81 a1 ef b8 b7

I think that's the two Unicode codepoints #8289 #65079

That's two characters, not one.

Perhaps it turns into one character if you apply normalize-unicode(), I don't know.